# display duplicate value using pandas.duplicated function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with a column of integers i'm reading and I want to terminate the program if there is a duplicate value in the column, along with displaying the value that was found to be a duplicate. I am currently able to find if there are duplicates and terminate the program using:

```
for x in df.duplicated(['projectID']):  # projectID is the column header
    if x == True:
        sys.exit("ERROR: there is a duplicate projectID in the csv file. Terminating Program.")
```

but I want a way to tell the user which value is duplicated. This is where I stuck. I have no idea how to do so. I know there can be multiple duplicates but I'm content with saying

```
 sys.exit("ERROR: {0} is a duplicate projectID in the csv file. Terminating Program.". format(x))
```

to the first duplicate integer it finds. Any ideas for how the code would look?

CSV would look something like:

```
projectName, projectID
Alpha,1
Beta,2
Gamma,3
Delta,1
```

so the value '1' is a duplicate which I would like to display to the user.

Comment: Please include a data sample in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do that:

```
if df.projectID.duplicated().any():
    print("There are some duplicates:")
    print(f"The first duplicate value of 'projectID' is {df[df.projectID.duplicated()].projectID.iloc[0]}")
```

The output is:

```
There are some duplicates:
The first duplicate value of 'projectID' is 1
```

To explain the last line:

This is the full line:
`df[df.projectID.duplicated()].projectID.iloc[0]`

It's comprised of the following pieces:

1. Step 1: `df.projectID.duplicated()` - produced a Boolean series of which values are duplicates.
2. Step 2: `df[<step-1>]`: reduce the data frame to include only the values which are indeed duplicates.
3. Step 3: `<step-2>.projectID`: extract the `ProjectID` series from the reduced dataframe.
4. Step 4: `<step-3>.iloc[0]`: take the value in the first location of the duplicate `ProjectID` series. This is the value you'd like to print.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Is there any document/guide on this? I feel like I spent too long trying to figure it out myself and it bothers means it's a simple 2 line solution.